# How to upload single / multiple images using Apollo-server-express and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql, apollo-server

Image upload using Apollo server and mongodb database .

If any body has solution or reference, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Custom Scalar](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars) field using [graphql-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload) to upload.

Hope this helps!
If you have questions about this, let me know.

Comment: I tried but throwing errors like ,no imported members from upload express.

Comment: @Digen, did you use graphqlUploadExpress? Can you show me something about how are doing ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).